# Pandas: Convert list of lists to multiple columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I'm new to python and pandas and I would like to convert list of lists (which contains information I extracted from a bunch of files) to individual columns. I have checked quite a lot of posts on stackoverflow and haven't found anything working for me so far. However if you have come across anything similar please post the link in the comments.

---

I have a Dataframe like this (a representative example):

```
df:
        ID           Values_a                    

    0   1      [[1,20.1],[2,20.2]]         

    1   7      [[1,30.1],[2,30.2]]
```

Both lists (`[[1,20.1],[2,20.2]]` and `[[1,30.1],[2,30.2]]`) have the same length (and will always be) however the integer in the lists (`1` and `2`) in can be any numbers.

And I would like to convert `df` into a dataframe like this:

```
  Label     1(Number of the 1st ID)        7(Number of the 2nd ID)

    1        20.1                                30.1

    2        20.2                                30.2
```

Where there will be three columns:

- The first column (`Label`) contains the first number in of the lists (so in this case, we have interger `1` and `2`).
- The second column (`1`) has the first ID number as column title, and contains the second values of each lists (`20.1`, `20.2`).
- The third column contains the same information for ID number 7.

---

First, I used apply.(pd.Series) to split the list of lists to get something like this (which I call df2):

```
df2:
       ID         0                1    

    0  1       [1,20.1]         [2,20.2]       

    1  7       [1,30.1]         [2,30.2]
```

I though, I can use the same trick (apply.(pd.Series)) to split the columns again to get something like this:

```
   ID         0        1        2         3

0  1          1       20.1      2        20.2      

1  7          1       30.1      2        30.2
```

And then, figure out how to get from here to where I want to me.

I have written something like this to split the list again:

```
names = [x for x in df2.colmuns]

for name in names:
   df3 = df2[name].apply(pd.Series)
   print df3
```

In jupyter notebook, I get the following result (when I include `print df3` in the `for` loop to check the output):

```
      0     1
0    1.0   20.1
1    2.0   20.2
      0     1
0    1.0   30.1
1    2.0   30.2
```

If I do `df3.info()` in the for loop it tells me that I have two dataframes in df3. (Is this normal???)

If I call `df3`, this is what I get:

```
      0     1
0    1.0   30.1
1    2.0   30.2
```

It seems like I'm overwriting `df3` rather than append new data to `df3`.

So:

- How can I get around this problem? (maybe create a new dataframe and append the split columns the new dataframe?)
- How can I transform df3 to the DataFrame I want? I have a feeling that I need to reshape my dataframe however I'm not sure how to do so.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated..!!

Comment: Does `Value_a` values are all of the same length with first elements (in your case labels) from the one set (in your case {1, 2})?

Comment: @ tarashypka If I understand you correctly, 'value_a' values doesn't have the same length as the first elements in my case (I've truncated the dataframe for ease of viewing...Sorry...) 

        'ID           Values_a'                  

   ' 0   1      [[1,20.1],[2,20.2],[3,20.3], blah blah blah]'         

   ' 1   7      [[1,30.1],[2,30.2],[3,30.8], blah blah blah]  '

Comment: @ tarashypka However within the 'Value_a' column, all cells in that column have the same length of list.

Comment: Does `[[1,20.1],[2,20.2],[3,20.3], blah blah blah]` always have the same length as `[[1,30.1],[2,30.2],[3,30.8], blah blah blah] ` and always have the same first elements (in this case 1, 2, 3)?

Comment: So: 1. Both list will always have the same length; 2. The first elements could be something like 5, 7, 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the structure of data in the column `Values_a` here is a possible workaround

```
>> x = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 7],
>>                   'Values_a': [ [[1, 20.1], [2, 20.2]], 
>>                                 [[1, 30.1], [2, 30.2]] ] });
>> data = { ID: [v[1] for v in x.loc[x['ID'] == ID, 'Values_a'].values[0]]
>>          for ID in x['ID'] }
>> index = [v[0] for v in x['Values_a'].iloc[0]]
>> y = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)
      1     7
1  20.1  30.1
2  20.2  30.2
```

Though, I believe there exist a more simple and elegant solution with `groupby`.

Comment: Ohhh this is clever... I didn't think of using list/dictionary comprehension...!!Thank you very much this works very well with the actual df :)